# Flask redirect http from https on nginx

Tags: nginx, flask

I'm building web application with Flask + Nginx and served by ssl.
And I'd like to redirect to http site. So I use Flask's redirect API like below. But browser is redirected to https://my.some.site

What can I do to redirect to http?

```
redirect('http://my.some.site')
```

Comment: You'll need to look at your nginx config and see what it's doing... if might be redirecting again -so more info is going to be needed (your nginx config - suitably anonymised for instance...)

Answer (score 1):

I do this in the /etc/nginx/sites-available (and sites-enabled, with symlink) relevant file:

```
# Rewrite http requests to https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bananas.com;
    return 301 https://bananas.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;
    server_name bananas.com;

    [.. further NGINX server definitions,e.g., ssl definitions, location, etc ..]
}
```

I'd rather not even get to flask with an http request, so use NGINX to redirect.